# twitter bootstrap form arrange fields horizontally - play framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to build a form in play framework using twitter bootstrap framework.

I want to arrange controls in multiple rows. And I also want to have the validation messages that bootstrap provides. Is there a way to do this?

```
<form class="form">

    @****
    * This works
    *****@

    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input type="text" id="inputWarning" placeholder="placeholder">
        <input type="text" id="inputWarning" placeholder="placeholder">
    </div>

    @****
    * Why doesn't this work?
    *****@
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <div class="control-group warning">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Input with warning</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="inputWarning">
                <span class="help-inline">Something may have gone wrong</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group warning">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Input with warning</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="inputWarning">
                <span class="help-inline">Something may have gone wrong</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `form-horizontal` class as described in the [Twitter bootstrap documents](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) to build a horizontal form.

Play provides [Form template helpers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaFormHelpers) that make rendering a form a lot easier. Unfortunately the Twitter Bootstrap template helper that ships with Play doens't work with horizontal forms and will get [deprecated in the next play version](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/issues/834).

I think the best solution is to write your own Bootstrap template helper like f.ex. `app/views/twitterBootstrapInput.scala.html`

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)  

<div class="control-group @if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
  @if(elements.label.toString.nonEmpty) { <label class="control-label" for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label> }
  <div class="controls">
  @elements.input

    <p class="help-inline">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</p>  
}  
    @if(elements.hasErrors) { <p class="help-block">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</p> }  
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then build a horizontal form like this:

```
@(args...)

@import helper._
@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(twitterBootstrapInput.f) } 

@helper.form(routes.myRoute(args), 'class -> "form-horizontal") {
   @select(
     editOptions("highlightStyle"),
     Seq("abc" -> "def", "ghi" -> "jkl"),
     '_label -> "Source style:"
   )
}
```

Comment: thanks, but my question is a bit different. with twitterBootstrapInput field constructor, I can have one lable and one input in one line. But, what I want to do is have multiple input boxes in one line. if i use the @inputText helper, it creates every input box on separate line.